# how to use a SOAP server from node.js web server

Tags: node.js, soap

I have an existing, full featured, SOAP server that I have to use from node.js server code. I read about a node plugin, soap-js as a plugin. It seems to be old and not much is found on it.

Anybody knows about a node plugin for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend this plugin: https://npmjs.org/package/soap Its easy to use and the support is good.

Cheers.

Comment: Good suggestion. Also I would recommend to fetch last version from master branch, as it has couple important fixes comparing to 0.2.7 version